# Create a sparse matrix from a list of rows (sparse vectors)

Tags: python, python-3.x, scipy, sparse-matrix

I would like to efficiently create the following sparse matrix of dimension `(s, n1+n2)`:

```
v0 v1 
v0 v2 
v0 v3 
 ... 
v0 vs
```

given sparse vector `v0 (1, n1)` and a list of sparse vectors `(1, n2)` `l = [v1, ... , vs]`.

I have tried to use `coo_matrix()` but it was unsuccessful as it seems to only work if you have dense vectors:

```
left = coo_matrix(np.repeat(v0, s))
right = coo_matrix(l)
m = hstack((left, right))
```

**Edit 1:**

I have found a workaround that does not seem very efficient:

```
right = vstack([x for x in l])
left = vstack([v0 for i in range(len(l))])
m = hstack((left, right))
```

**Edit 2:**

This is an example (not working) to help you understand the situation.

```
from scipy.sparse import random, coo_matrix
from numpy import repeat

s = 10
n1 = 3
n2 = 5

v0 = random(1, n1)
l = [random(1, n2) for i in range(s)]

left = coo_matrix(repeat(v0, s))
right = coo_matrix(l)
m = hstack((left, right))
```

Comment: Please add an example to make clear what exactly you want with what kind of data. In some interpretations, this makes no sense (dense vs. sparse).

Comment: The vectors are results of TfidfVectorizer.fit_transform(...)

Comment: It does not matter. Try to explain a bit more. A hand-build example would help. (and this method probably does not ouput dim(X,**2**))

Comment: Still unclear. The usage / dims of v0 seems to be conflicting between the first example and edit 2. Also: please fix the code. Don't let us reverse-engineer your imports (random). Simple rule: if we can copy/paste and observe the same as you, it's fine.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
In [1]: from scipy import sparse

In [2]: s, n1, n2 = 10,3,5
In [3]: v0 = sparse.random(1, n1)
In [4]: v0
Out[4]: 
<1x3 sparse matrix of type '<class 'numpy.float64'>'
    with 0 stored elements in COOrdinate format>
In [5]: l = [sparse.random(1, n2) for i in range(s)]
In [6]: l
Out[6]: 
[<1x5 sparse matrix of type '<class 'numpy.float64'>'
    with 0 stored elements in COOrdinate format>,
  ...
 <1x5 sparse matrix of type '<class 'numpy.float64'>'
    with 0 stored elements in COOrdinate format>]
```

Instead of `np.repeat` use `sparse.vstack` to create a stack of `V0` copies

```
In [7]: V0 = sparse.vstack([v0]*s)
In [8]: V0
Out[8]: 
<10x3 sparse matrix of type '<class 'numpy.float64'>'
    with 0 stored elements in COOrdinate format>
```

Similarly convert the list of `n2` matrices into one matrix:

```
In [10]: V1 = sparse.vstack(l)
In [11]: V1
Out[11]: 
<10x5 sparse matrix of type '<class 'numpy.float64'>'
    with 0 stored elements in COOrdinate format>
```

Now join them:

```
In [12]: m = sparse.hstack((V0,V1))
In [13]: m
Out[13]: 
<10x8 sparse matrix of type '<class 'numpy.float64'>'
    with 0 stored elements in COOrdinate format>
```

I won't make any claims about this being efficient. `hstack` and `vstack` use `bmat` (check their code).  `bmat` collects the `coo` attributes of all the blocks, and joins them (with offsets) into the inputs to a new `coo_matrix` call (again, the code is readable).  So you could avoid some intermediate conversions by using `bmat` directly, or even playing with the `coo` attributes directly.  But `hstack` and `vstack` are relatively intuitive.